# Groovy 2.0.1, GroovyCastException on my own class?

Tags: java, groovy

I'm extensively using groovy classes in my web app project. I can create an instance of a type (defined as a groovy class) but can never at a later time cast back to it (`GroovyCastException` occurs).

> org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object 'com.company.role.delegation.ProfileModel@49ee6848' with class 'com.company.role.delegation.ProfileModel' to class 'com.company.role.delegation.ProfileModel'

According to the above error message, the source and destination class types are the same. Huh?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most likely the reason is that the class have been loaded twice via different classloaders. Check if the getClass().getClassLoader() for both the instances are identical.

Comment: How do you fix this issue? I'm getting it in Katalon Studio.

Comment: @MikeWarren make sure you have only one version of the library in the running process.

Comment: @AntonArhipov Why would it be a problem to load the same class in different classloaders ?

Comment: @Louis a class is identified in JVM as a full name with a package + the classloader. Loading the same class from different class loaders causes the 2 classes to be different from the runtime point of view, hence if you try to cast one to another will cause a ClassCastException.