# Strange cast exception in Groovy script

Tags: eclipse, groovy

When I try to run my groovy script in Eclipse, I get a cast exception like:

> org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object 'package.Config@6babd36b' with class 'package.Config' to class 'package.Config'

The exception occurs when I instantiate another object using the `Config as parameter`.

```
clazz.newInstance(config: config)
```

To me, this seems very odd. But perhaps someone out there can bring me an explanation?

Comment: Share the code that causes the problem.

Comment: It is a simplification of the problem, and the code ran ok before.

Comment: Therefore it seems impossible to reproduce and the solve :/

Comment: I thought so, but still someone may have had this problem before, hence my attempt

Comment: I found another person with the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12272035/groovy-2-0-1-groovycastexception-on-my-own-class

Comment: So upvote the answer and question if it work for You ;)

Comment: The other post was correct. I DID have more than one classloader:

    groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader$InnerLoader@7a06cf15
and  
    org.codehaus.groovy.tools.RootLoader@32728d

Comment: It seems like an Eclipse issue with run configurations and the groovy plugin: http://octodecillion.com/blog/groovy-classloaders-eclips/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved! :)

In the Eclipse run configuration, I looked at the argument tab and noticed that both source files and compiled class files was part of the classpath parameter:

```
--classpath "${workspace_loc:/groovyscripts}/src/main/groovy:...
...:${workspace_loc:/groovyscripts}/classes"
```

the above setting gives different classloaders for my config object (loaded from src/) and the target field (loaded from classes/)

```
groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader$InnerLoader@7a06cf15 
org.codehaus.groovy.tools.RootLoader@32728d
```

Removing the first reference to the source files resulted in a successful run. Classloaders after removal is ONLY RootLoader.

```
org.codehaus.groovy.tools.RootLoader@32728d
```

**The answer is to remove the source from the classpath in arguments tab in Eclipse.**

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add some information for this topic. Maybe somebody will find it useful.
I received same error then was trying to compile groovy script for using in multithread environment:

```
 GroovyClassLoader groovyClassLoader = new GroovyClassLoader();
 Class<? extends Script> clazz = groovyClassLoader.parseClass(groovyCode);
 return clazz.newInstance();
```

But by default GroovyClassLoader are using ClassLoader of current thread:

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader())
```

So, you can pickup one class loader and use it for all threads. Or avoid shared groovy stuff :)